# customized JSON output in pig

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

Need customized JSON output-- 
(I have two files - text file and schema file)

**abc.txt -**

100002030,Tom,peter,eng,block 3, lane 5,california,10021

100003031,Tom,john,doc,block 2, lane 2,california,10021

100004032,Tom,jim,eng,block 1, lane 1,california,10021

100005033,Tom,trek,doc,block 2, lane 2,california,10021

100006034,Tom,peter,eng,block 6, lane 6,california,10021

**abc_schema.txt   (field name and position)**

rollno         1

firstname      2

lastname       3

qualification  4

address1       5

address2       6

city           7

Zipcode        8

**Rules-**

- First 6 characters of rollno
- Need to club address1 | address2 | city
- Prefix Address to above

**Expected Output-**

{"rollno":"100002","firstname":"Tom","lastname:"peter","qualification":"eng","Address":"block 3 lane 5 california","zipcode":"10021"}

{"rollno":"100002","firstname":"Tom","lastname:"john","qualification":"doc","Address":"block 2 lane 2 california","zipcode":"10021"}

{"rollno":"100004","firstname":"Tom","lastname:"jim","qualification":"eng","Address":"block 1 lane 1 california","zipcode":"10021"}

{"rollno":"100005","firstname":"Tom","lastname:"trek","qualification":"doc","Address":"block 2 lane 2 california","zipcode":"10021"}

{"rollno":"100006","firstname":"Tom","lastname:"peter","qualification":"eng","Address":"block 6 lane 6 california","zipcode":"10021"}

**I do not wish to hardcode the fields but read from the schema file,  the idea is to have reusable code. Something like looping schema file and the text file**

Answer (score 0):

```
A = load 'abc.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (rollno, Fname,Lname,qua,add1,add2,city,Zipcode);

B = foreach A generate rollno, Fname,Lname,qua,concate (add1,add2,city) ,Zipcode;


C= STORE B
    INTO 'first_table.json' 
    USING JsonStorage();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please help with a configurable solution as I would like to avoid specifying schema information while loading. BUT prefer reading it on run time. Probably NESTED FOREACH can help ?